# grep and return line continuations?

Tags: regex, grep, pcre, pcregrep

I want grep to return results through line continuations, ie input file like:

```
$ cat input.txt
abba \
  jjjj \
  nnnn

$ grep "abba ?" input.txt
abba jjjj nnnn
```

I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: ? It seems to work as you get *some* result. Please expand. Isn't the result what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this where you search in your file after replacing slashes with newlines...

```
tr '\\' '\n' < input.txt | grep something
```

Comment: Selecting this as the answer. I ended up doing something like this-- but there is probably a better solution.